# selecting column n and rows m of matrix/dataframe where n and m are based on another vector

Tags: r

I have been stumbling around on this and haven't quite cracked it - any help would be greatly appreciated.

say I have a data frame as below

```
data = data.frame((matrix(1:40, ncol = 10)))

    X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10
  1  1  5  9 13 17 21 25 29 33  37
  2  2  6 10 14 18 22 26 30 34  38
  3  3  7 11 15 19 23 27 31 35  39
  4  4  8 12 16 20 24 28 32 36  40
```

Now for row one 1 of my new data set I want only data from row 2 and columns 4:6 of data, row 2 of my new data set I want data from row 1 columns 7:9 of data, for row 3 of my new data set I want row 2 columns 1:3 and row 4 I want row 4 columns 2:4

so I essentially I want to a smaller new data subset which looks like

```
14 18 22
25 29 33
2  6  10 
8  12 16
```

the columns I want to recover for each row I can define as a matrix like this

```
columns = matrix(c(4:6,7:9,1:3,2:4), nrow = 4, byrow = TRUE)

      [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    4    5    6
[2,]    7    8    9
[3,]    1    2    3
[4,]    2    3    4
```

and the rows I want to recover from data are

```
 rows = c(2,1,2,4)
```

I have tried the following below unsuccessfully any solution would be greatly appreciated?

```
data[rows, columns]
data[cbind(rows,columns)]
```

Comment: you want to use "columns" and "rows" to subset your matrix ? You should also modify the expected output in this case.

Answer (score 3):

You can use matrix integer indexation to subset your matrix and create a new one:

```
 matrix(dat[cbind(rows,as.vector(columns))],nrow=length(rows))

#       [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]   14   18   22
# [2,]   25   29   33
# [3,]    2    6   10
# [4,]    8   12   16
```

Comment: Thanks for the amazingly fast response, I slightly changed my question while you were answering as I realised I had a slight error. But again thanks for the speedy response.

Comment: @rphi6876 you want to use "columns" and "rows" to subset your matrix ? You should also modify the expected output in this case